# Changing connection string in DLL that is included in executable projects

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, dll

I have a project that is executable and I created a dll, which includes commonly used datasets among projects (DLLforApp and App).

[DLLforApp]

1. a separate project from App but in the same solution.
2. this is a class library project which creates a dll file
3. this has a connection string which is  DLLforApp.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString

[App]

1. another project in the same solution.
2. this project includes a reference for a set of datasets.. which is DLLforApp
3. This project also has a connection string which is the same as DLLforApp.

Now, if I compile this project the following would be expected outputs..

```
App.exe
DLLforApp.dll
App.exe.config 
...
```

I can change the connection string for App.exe inside App.exe.config, but how do I change connection string for DLLforApp.dll ? 
changing connection string in App does not affect the connection string for DLLforApp..

so, what I am doing now is..

In the DataSet designer select the TableAdapter section and change the property ConnectionModifier from Internal to Public.

In forms that use DLLforApp.datasets:

```
public Form1()

{

InitializeComponent();

customersTableAdapter1.Connection = new SqlConnection(WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.MyConnection);

}
```

this will reset the connection for each tableadapter everytime.. 
is it the only way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

in .net, the entire application uses the same set of configuration entries. In your DLLforApp project, you can comfortably ask for a connection string, presuming it will be defined somewhere, like in the app.exe.config, or if you prefer, you can create a dllforapp.dll.config file, and it will load from that config file too.

Comment: I was not able to see the connection string of app.exe.config in DLLforApp project. well, what I have is 

Solution 

- App project (namespace App)
- DLLforApp project (namespace DLLforApp)

If I try to add a new dataset in DLLforApp I can only pick a connection string within DLLforApp project..

Comment: Can you expound on "I was not able to see the connection string of app.exe.config in DllForApp project."?

Comment: @Jin are you trying to add a new TableAdapter? It doesn't load config strings at design time. You have to tell it how to connect to the database manually, but you can specify not to use that same connection to load the tableadapter at runtime. You can have it load from a config file, in which case either will work.

Comment: Well, it looks like it can load from config strings at design time, but only if it's stored in a settings file?

Comment: yes only if it is stored in the settings.. 
I will edit my question for more clarification

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a section for the dll's config,so add this inside your applications `.config` file. So inside the section `<configSections> ... </configSections>` (There will be some there for you Main Application) add this:

```
<sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
    <section name="MyNameSpace.MyDll.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
</sectionGroup>
```

and then since you've named the group 'applicationSettings' you'll need to add this under `<configuration> ... </configuration>`

```
  <applicationSettings>
    <MyNameSpace.MyDll.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="ConnectionString" serializeAs="String">
        <value>My connectionString</value>
      </setting>
    </MyNameSpace.MyDll.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
```

That should give you a head start, I've done the same thing for a DAL DLL that needed special config for one application - which is where I've copied this from.